# Categorize values in columns under a certain threshold into a different column, else keep the column as is

Tags: r

I have data on COVID-19 variants and the proportion of genetic sequences sequenced for a particular variant on a weekly basis (mock data below).

```
df <- data.frame(
  Week_Count = seq(1,3),
  "Omicron BN.1" = c(0.05, 0.05, 0.10),
    "Omicron BA.5" = c(0.75, 0.50, 0.65),
    "Omicron CH.1" = c(0.10, 0.25, 0.10),
    Other = c(0.10, 0.20, 0.15))

> df
  Week_Count Omicron.BN.1 Omicron.BA.5 Omicron.CH.1 Other
1          1         0.05         0.75         0.10  0.10
2          2         0.05         0.50         0.25  0.20
3          3         0.10         0.65         0.10  0.15
```

What I would like to do is identify the columns that stay under a threshold- for this example, identify variants whose observations do not supersede 0.1 (i.e., identify the column observations that are less than or equal to 0.1), and for those columns who do stay less than or equal to 0.1,  categorize/add them to the `Other` column (which means `Other` should not be changed/re-categorized). It is important to note that columns who even have 1 observation that is larger than 0.1 should remain as is in the dataset (look at `Omicron.CH.1` as an example). Ideal output would look as follows-

```
  Week_Count  Omicron.BA.5 Omicron.CH.1 Other
1          1     0.75         0.10       0.15
2          2     0.50         0.25       0.25
3          3     0.65         0.10       0.25
```

This seems to me like it may be complex code, would you mind explaining your solution? Thanks so much.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

a base R solution

```
df$Other <- rowSums(subset(df, select = sapply(df, \(x) all(x <= 0.1)))) + df$Other
df <- subset(df, select = !sapply(df, \(x) all(x <= 0.1)))

#    Week_Count Omicron.BA.5 Omicron.CH.1 Other
# 1          1         0.75         0.10  0.15
# 2          2         0.50         0.25  0.25
# 3          3         0.65         0.10  0.25
```

functionality:

`sapply(df, \(x) all(x <= 0.1)))` return a TRUE/FALSE vector of columns where all values are below 0.1
This vector is first used so sum this subset of columns with the existing df$Other column (and overwrite the Other column with these new values).
And then used again to subset all columns where the all <= 0.1 is not (`!...`) TRUE

Comment: Thank you so much, I appreciate you breaking down your code as I would not have been able to interpret pieces of it.

Answer (score 1):

```
idx <- colSums(df[2:4]<=0.1) == nrow(df)
df$Other <- df$Other + rowSums(df[2:4][idx])
df[2:4][idx] <- NULL
df

  Week_Count Omicron.BN.1 Omicron.BA.5 Omicron.CH.1 Other
1          1         0.75         0.10         0.75  0.15
2          2         0.50         0.25         0.50  0.25
3          3         0.65         0.10         0.65  0.25
```